# Copy row from non-active sheet to another sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, worksheet

I would like to copy the entire first row of one sheet to another.
But I'll settle for just copying a specific range.
I'm using

```
    dim wb as workbook
    set wb = Thisworkbook
    sheetname = "sourcesheet"
    wb.worksheets(sheetname).range("a1:ak1").copy
```

I keep getting the error runtime error 1004, "Application-defined or object defined error"
I don't have the paste statement, because I can't get past this one.
Obviously I want this to work in the general case and since I'm going to be copy a lot of rows from different spreadsheets I don't want to keep changing the active page.

The sheet 'sheetname' exists.

Comment: there's no problem with that code...

Comment: Where is this code located? The capitalization is wrong. It should be `Dim` , `As`, `Workbook`, `Set`, `ThisWorkbook`, `Worksheets`, `Range` and `Copy`.

Comment: while the active sheet name is not "sourcesheet", if you put `wb.worksheets(sheetname).activate` ---> is the sheet named "sourcesheet" activated ?

Comment: try adding to this statement to the end of yours `.copy destination:= activesheet.range("A1:AK1")`

Comment: The actual code is on a private network. I hand-copied this small piece to the website, so it didn't do the autocapitalization that vba does.

Comment: wb.worksheets(sheetname).activate works (the sheet is activated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the error you received but I would suggest considering not using copy but instead just setting one range values to another range:

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    sheetname = "sourcesheet"
    wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1:ak1").Value2 = wb.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("a1:ak1").Value2
```

Comment: I'll try that shortly. thanks